# MYSQL - Search in 2 columns with one search term

Tags: mysql, search, pdo

**I have a search query to search my users table** for the search term entered by the user.
**My query searches in 3 rows**:
`user_last_name`
`user_first_name`
`user_business_address`
Everything works fine as long as the user searches for one of the rows at a time.
Let's say user_first_name is 'Alex' and user_last_name is 'Smith'. If I search for 'Alex' or 'Smith' everything works fine.

---

**The Problem**
When the user searches for 'Alex Smith' as soon as the space key is hit there are no results shown anymore.
**How can I search in both rows?**
**How do I deal with the whitespace?**

---

**My search query**

```
$term = strip_tags('%'.$_GET['term'].'%');

$query = $database->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_last_name LIKE :term OR user_first_name LIKE :term OR user_business_address LIKE :term ORDER BY user_id  LIMIT 10");
$query->execute(array(':term' => $term));

$count = $query->fetchColumn();

if ($count >= 1) {
    $query2 = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_last_name LIKE :term OR user_first_name LIKE :term OR user_business_address LIKE :term ORDER BY user_id  LIMIT 10");
    $query2->execute(array(':term' => $term));

    $results = $query2->fetchAll();
}
```

Please let me know if you would like to see any more code.
I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: Do you mean search in 3 _columns_ ?

Comment: You can use php's trim() function to trim whitespace additions at the beginning and end of your search term as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `LIKE` to look for an exact match, use a single equal sign (=) .

Secondly, you can use `CONCAT` to combine first name and last name :

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE concat(user_first_name,' ',user_last_name) = :term 
ORDER BY user_id  LIMIT 10
```

I removed the last condition `user_business_address like :term` since you didn't explain what is it for.

If the user will input either first name/last name or full name, then you can use the `LIKE` operation with `%` wildcard :

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE concat(user_first_name,' ',user_last_name) LIKE concat('%',:term,'%')
ORDER BY user_id  LIMIT 10"
```

[Here is a document on like operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) .

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from users where user_first_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) ,
TRIM( SUBSTR(fullname, LOCATE(' ', fullname)) ) AS last_name FROM registeredusers
```

There's a bunch of cool things you can do with substr, locate, substring_index, etc. Check the manual for some real confusion. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will have a look into substr, locate etc.